# Print the entire row which has difference in value while compare the columns

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to print the entire row whose value dont match

EG :

```
Symbol Qty       Symbol Qty         Symbol qty

a      10          a     10           a    11


b      11          b     11           b    11

c      12          c     12           f    13 

f      12          f      12          g    13
```

OUTPUT :

```
a   10    a      10        a    11 

c   12    c      12        (empty Space)

f 12      f       12    f    13

empty space    {ES}         g   13
```

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a ) '  output1.csv output2.csv  >> finn1.csv
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a ) '  finn1.csv output4.csv  >> finn.csv
```

but this prints all in one column that is missing 
Like a 11, but I require the whole line

Comment: Do you only want to test the `Qty` field, or do you want to output mismatched `Symbol` fields as well?

Comment: Then the script in my Answer (below) should do the job :).

Comment: 1) Why are the three columns?  Why does The third column have different headers?

Comment: 2) Why does the first empty space appear AFTER the data for 'c', but the second empty space appears BETWEEN the data points for 'f'?

Comment: 3) Please explain the real world requirement here. It seems to be related to stock data. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So.. Is this file a concatenation of data from 3 separate files? If so, can we work on the three original files instead? That would simplify the logic considerably.

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand the problem you are trying to solve. Without a full understanding of the problem, I can't produce a solution.  Can you describe the full problem in words? What you appear to have done so far is to create part of the solution and ask us to fill in the missing pieces. But without understanding the full problem, I don't even know how much of the solution is missing.

Comment: Could you please have a look at the quetion I dont see any other easire way to explain. It basically has to compare the symbol against the value and if the value is present in all 3 rows then ignore if the value is different or missing then populate that row in organised way like AAPL should all be in one line , next symbol should be in the other line etc

Comment: I have read the question and I see the example and I still do not understand. This is why I have asked you to rewrite the question to include the FULL problem you are trying to solve. For example, your LATEST change to the example now has 3 inputs for 'f', all the same, but 'f' is in the output twice, separated by an empty space. I am sorry, but I cannot respond further until the complete problem is described.

Comment: apologies it should return 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only want to test for mismatched `Qty` fields, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare    input_file="/path/to/input_file"

declare -i header_flag=0 a b c
while read line; do
  [ ${header_flag} -eq 0 ] && header_flag=1 && continue   # Ignore first line.
  [ ${#line} -eq 0 ] && continue                          # Ignore blank lines.
  read x a x b x c x <<< ${line}         # Reuse ${x} because it is not used.
  [ ${a} -ne ${b} -o ${a} -ne ${c} -o ${b} -ne ${c} ] && echo ${line}
done < ${input_file}
```

Comment: OK.  You have changed the question so my Answer is now invalid. The input and output examples are very different from your original post. I no longer understand what you are trying to achieve. I am adding comments to the original question.

Comment: Its the same I have just added a parameter where if it doesnt find the same qty for a particular symbol then just return empty space

Answer (score 0):

The awk one-liner

```
awk '!($1 == $3 && $2 == $4 && $3 == $5 && $4 == $6)' file
```

will output

```
Symbol Qty       Symbol Qty         Symbol qty
a      10          a     10           a    11
c      12          c     12           f    12
f      12          f      12          g    13
```

---

You're going about this the wrong way: you can't mash up all the files into one and then try to find which ones have different/missing values. You need to process the individual files

```
$ cat file1
Symbol Qty
a      10
b      11
c      12
f      12
$ cat file2
Symbol Qty
a     10
b     11
c     12
f      12
$ cat file3
Symbol qty
a    11
b    11
f    13
g    13
```

Then
assuming you have GNU awk

```
gawk '
  FNR > 1 { qty[$1][FILENAME] = $1 " " $2 }
  END {
    OFS = "\t"
    for (sym in qty) {
      missing = !((ARGV[1] in qty[sym]) && (ARGV[2] in qty[sym]) && (ARGV[3] in qty[sym]))
      unequal = !(qty[sym][ARGV[1]] == qty[sym][ARGV[2]] && qty[sym][ARGV[1]] == qty[sym][ARGV[3]])
      if (missing || unequal) {
        print qty[sym][ARGV[1]], qty[sym][ARGV[2]], qty[sym][ARGV[3]]
      }
    }
  }
' file{1,2,3}
```

outputs

```
a 10    a 10    a 11
c 12    c 12
f 12    f 12    f 13
                g 13
```

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. If you only want to compare the symbol columns, why is `a 10  a 10  a 11` in your output?

Comment: This solution requires GNU awk for the array-of-arrays. Requires some tweaks for non-GNU

Comment: Just remove `FNR > 1` -- not the whole line, just that part.

Comment: Its still throwing error at line 1 , 5 , 6,  7 and 8.                    gawk '
    { qty[$1][output1.csv] = $1 " " $2 }
    END {
        OFS = "\t"
            for (sym in qty) {
                  missing = !((ARGV[1] in qty[sym]) && (ARGV[2] in qty[sym]) && (ARGV[3] in qty[sym]))

Comment: unequal = !(qty[sym][ARGV[1]] == qty[sym][ARGV[2]] && qty[sym][ARGV[1]] == qty[sym][ARGV[3]])
                              if (missing || unequal) {
                                      print qty[sym][ARGV[1]], qty[sym][ARGV[2]], qty[sym][ARGV[3]]
                                            }
                                                }
                                                  }
                                                  ' file{output1.csv,output2.csv,output4.csv} > ReconFinaloutput.csv

Comment: could you check if that correct ? since it was 2 big I have added as 2 comments .

Comment: you mean to use GNU awk inplace of gawk